# React Native Firebase- Email address badly formatted (auth/invalid-email)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I am creating a login/registration system with React Native and Firebase. I have two files `Login.js` and `SignUp.js`. I have almost same code for both of the files and both of them are giving me the same error. I am showing only my `SignUp.js` file here.
I logged the value of variable `email` in my console and I can see that the value is totally correct.

**Note:** This problem doesn't always occur. This works properly with some email addresses, but with some it doesn't work properly. Even though the email addresses exist.

First of all I imported the variable `auth` from `firebase.js` file like this

```js
import { auth } from "../firebase";
```

Then in the exported function, I defined three states like this:

```js
const [name, setName] = useState("");
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
```

After that, I created three TextInputs and connected them with their states like this:

```js
<View style={styles.inputField}>
          <MaterialIcons
            style={{ marginRight: 15 }}
            name="email"
            size={28}
            color="#929292"
          />
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Enter your email address"
            style={styles.textInput}
            onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
            value={email}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputField}>
          <FontAwesome
            name="lock"
            size={30}
            color="#929292"
            style={{ marginRight: 20, marginLeft: 5 }}
          />
          <TextInput
            secureTextEntry={true}
            placeholder="Enter your password"
            style={styles.textInput}
            onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
            value={password}
          />
        </View>
```

And my signUp function is like this:

```js
  const signUp = () => {
    auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((authUser) => {
        authUser.user.updateProfile({
          displayName: name,
        });
        props.navigation.replace("Home");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error.message);
      });
  };
```

Now can anyone help me to resolve my error? For more information, I am sending the entire `SignUp.js` file.

```js
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { Ionicons, MaterialIcons, FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { auth } from "../firebase";

const SignUp = (props) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const signUp = () => {
    auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((authUser) => {
        authUser.user.updateProfile({
          displayName: name,
        });
        props.navigation.replace("Home");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error.message);
      });
  };
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <Image
        style={styles.signupImage}
        source={require(".././assets/images/signup.png")}
      />
      <Text style={styles.headerText}>Sign up to get started!</Text>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <View style={styles.inputField}>
          <Ionicons
            style={{ marginRight: 18 }}
            name="person"
            size={24}
            color="#929292"
          />
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Enter your name"
            style={styles.textInput}
            onChangeText={(text) => setName(text)}
            value={name}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputField}>
          <MaterialIcons
            style={{ marginRight: 15 }}
            name="email"
            size={28}
            color="#929292"
          />
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Enter your email address"
            style={styles.textInput}
            onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
            value={email}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputField}>
          <FontAwesome
            name="lock"
            size={30}
            color="#929292"
            style={{ marginRight: 20, marginLeft: 5 }}
          />
          <TextInput
            secureTextEntry={true}
            placeholder="Enter your password"
            style={styles.textInput}
            onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
            value={password}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={signUp} style={styles.signUpButton}>
        <Text style={styles.signUpButtonText}>Sign Up</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={styles.bottomContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.bottomText}>Already have an account?</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Login")}>
          <Text style={styles.loginButton}>Login instead!</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

export default SignUp;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#E5F0F6",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
  },
  signupImage: {
    marginTop: 20,
    height: 350,
    width: 350,
  },
  headerText: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 26,
    color: "#002642",
  },
  inputContainer: {
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginTop: 20,
    width: "70%",
  },
  inputField: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    padding: 5,
    borderBottomColor: "#929292",
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
  },
  signUpButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#0085FF",
    marginTop: 30,
    padding: 10,
    width: "60%",
    borderRadius: 50,
    alignItems: "center",
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  signUpButtonText: {
    color: "#E5F0F6",
    fontSize: 18,
  },
  bottomContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    padding: 5,
    marginBottom: 50,
  },
  bottomText: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  loginButton: {
    color: "#0085FF",
    fontSize: 16,
    marginLeft: 5,
  },
});
```

Comment: Check the value of `email` being passed to `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword`

Comment: @James I checked, it's correct.

Comment: Please try to add email `trim()` method when you pass it email on firebase `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.trim(), password)`

Comment: @JavascriptHuppTechnologies Hey dude, thank you. I just fixed the issue by doing what you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. All I had to do is trim the email address. Like this

```js
  const signUp = () => {
    auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.trim(), password)
      .then((authUser) => {
        authUser.user.updateProfile({
          displayName: name,
        });
        props.navigation.replace("Home");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error.message);
      });
  };
```